# Why is InfoPath letting me do edit controls in real-time?

Tags: infopath

This an odd error. Infopath is letting me to change (move around, delete, expand, etc.) controls of the form in real time as if I was in in design mode. It happens for a particular view, not all of them.

I don't want this. Does anybody know what could I've done to cause this and/or how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened, but I copied the controls into a new view and that resolved the issue.